# Resizing canvas for the app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-canvas

we have been trying to setup the height for a canvas app without luck.

this is the code we are using

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
// assume we are already logged in
FB.init({appId: '<?=$fb_app_id ?>', xfbml: true, oauth : true,cookie: true});
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
function sizeChangeCallback() {
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 950);
}
```

We tried both without the sizechangecallback

and our settings set to Fixed and Fixed 950

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you setup the fixed height parameter in your application settings,
you can call `FB.Canvas.setSize` to change the page height.

If your page height changes dynamically, you can run `FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading`
to check if Canvas is loaded and run `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow`.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // assume we are already logged in
    FB.init({ appId: '<?=$fb_app_id ?>', xfbml: true, oauth: true, cookie: true });

    FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 950 });

    FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading( function(response) {
        console.log(response.time_delta_ms);
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    });
}
```

FB Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading/