# how to dynamically increse the height in facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, asp.net-4.0

I used to **FB.Arbiter.inform('setSize', { width: 760, height: 1485 })** increse the height for my facebook app.It's working yesterday, but today is not working.If you know how to dynamically  increse the height in facebook app ,give some information about this.

Comment: Not sure this is exactly what you're after, but have you looked at `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()` ?

Comment: it is increase the height, but i want fix the height of the page.FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow() is increse the height like tree

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270906/resizing-canvas-for-the-app/11272062#11272062

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, after you setup the fixed height parameter in your application settings,
you can call `FB.Canvas.setSize` to change the page height.

If your page height changes dynamically, you can run `FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading`
to check if Canvas is loaded and run `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow`.

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 950 });

FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading( function(response) {
    console.log(response.time_delta_ms);
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
});
```

FB Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading/

Comment: Thanks for the giving the idea,it realy working.it is increase the height , but i click on the hide  button, it decrease the height.Do u have idea on this, u  will share information for me.

Comment: You have a button where you hide/show content and you have user action change your page height? setAutoGrow() will run once your page loaded with setDoneLoading().

Comment: hide/show client click using the java script. js method as folows,var heig=800; FB.Arbiter.inform('setSize',{width: 760, height: + heig }); 
            FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading( function(response) {           
            alert("height:" + response.time_delta_ms);
            FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
          });
            });

Comment: Update your question, don't write all this code in comments, loosing my eyes here!

Answer (score 1):

After all, the real problem is from facebook with http**s**

You can follow the issue here:

> https://developers.facebook.com/live_status

Everything else is ok, just change setAutoResize to setAutoGrow

Regards