# How to set pagetabs height to auto with no scroll bars?

Tags: facebook, tabs, height, scrollbar

My page tab always has scroll bars if the page in the iframe is greater than 800px. I see there is a 'set canvas height to fluid' in that advanced setting but that dosen't seem to help. I've tried other suggestions like adding

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Canvas.setSize();
   }
   // Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
   function sizeChangeCallback() {
    FB.Canvas.setSize();
   }
   </script>
```

but doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be clear: Have you embedded the JavaScript SDK into your page _and_ correctly initialized it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that worked after trying the suggestions above and many other possible fixes was to create a new facebook app.

I did use the following code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
```

But even that would not work until I created a new app.
I don't know for sure but I think the original app may have been corrupt or too old.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this CSS style in your CSS file, or in the header of your HTML files,

```
<style type="text/css">
body { overflow:hidden; }
</style>
```

And here i have answer a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11324976/555760,
about the Canvas `setSize()`, `setDoneLoading()` and `setAutoGrow()`,

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 950 });

FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading( function(response) {
    console.log(response.time_delta_ms);
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
});
```