# facebook set fluid from javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas, size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to dynamically increse the height in facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323299/how-to-dynamically-increse-the-height-in-facebook-app)

I am developing flash app for Facebook, fluid layout is best for me except when my user resolution is to small, I wish Facebook had a minimum property for canvas size.

So until they will implement it I wish to change my canvas setting from JavaScript, is it possible to set dynamically my canvas settings size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already answer a similar question here:
[how to dynamically increse the height in facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323299/how-to-dynamically-increse-the-height-in-facebook-app/11324976#11324976)

You have to set `FB.Canvas.setSize()` and later check if canvas loaded with `FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading()` and in the response you can run the `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()`

An example:

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 950 });

FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading( function(response) {
    console.log(response.time_delta_ms);
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. However you should be able to achieve your desired user experience working with the methods [`FB.Canvas.setSize`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/) and [`FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/) depending on the user resolution.